# Selecting count into multiple columns

Tags: sql-server

I have a table like this

```
MonthYear  JobType   JobID
01-2014    FullTime  1
01-2014    PartTime  2
02-2014    FullTime  3
03-2014    FullTime  4
04-2014    PartTime  5
04-2014    PartTime  6
04-2014    FullTime  7
```

I want to select the count of each job type grouped by MonthYear as follows.

```
MonthYear  FullTime  PartTime
01-2014    1         1
02-2014    1         0
03-2014    1         0
04-2014    1         2
```

Can anyone suggest how to achieve this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT MonthYear,
SUM(CASE WHEN JobType='FullTime' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as FullTime ,
SUM(CASE WHEN JobType='PartTime' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as PartTime
FROM t
GROUP BY MonthYear
```

Answer (score 0):

Pivot solution:

```
SELECT
  [MonthYear],
  [FullTime],
  [PartTime]
FROM 
 (values
  ('01-2014', 'FullTime',1),
  ('01-2014', 'PartTime',2),
  ('02-2014', 'FullTime',3),
  ('03-2014', 'FullTime',4),
  ('04-2014', 'PartTime',5),
  ('04-2014', 'PartTime',6),
  ('04-2014', 'FullTime',7)) x(MonthYear, JobType, JobID)
PIVOT (count(JobType)  
for JobType
in([FullTime],[PartTime])  
)as p 
ORDER BY MonthYear
```